# Cmake for Intel OpenVino project complains about feature_defs and missing OpenVino extensions directory

Tags: cmake, computer-vision, intel, openvino

I tried to compile this OpenVino sample project: https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/intruder-detector

When I do the cmake, I don't know why it is asking for feature_def, I don't understand what that means.

I'm also troubled at how `/opt/intel//computer_vision_sdk_2018.4.420/deployment_tools/inference_engine/samples/extension` is said to be a non-existent directory. It indeed does not exist. i tried reinstalling OpenVino several times, and that did not solve the problem. Please help, any advice will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    feature_defs


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source
      "/opt/intel//computer_vision_sdk_2018.4.420/deployment_tools/inference_engine/samples/extension"
  which is not an existing directory.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/intruder-    detector/application/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like quite a complete problem as the repo isn't maintained properly. I do not have a full, direct solution to your problem but hopefully this will guide you in the right direction (if you don't want to wait for the owners to do the changes).

[This fairly recent git issue](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/store-traffic-monitor/issues/2) asked for fixes for essentially the same exact problem you have, except on another project in that repo. That being said, it seems it has been fixed there.

Sadly, the fix commits are a massive reupload of the whole project with new, updated files; the CMakeLists included. The new [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/store-traffic-monitor/blob/dc38f699960ce2d14029aa9776f0b29682f05421/application/CMakeLists.txt) (found [here](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/store-traffic-monitor/tree/dc38f699960ce2d14029aa9776f0b29682f05421/application)) of that project is your best bet at fixing the issue yourself, by comparing it to yours and figuring out the changes here and there. However, since the whole thing was modified, it's possible that the dependencies and such aren't too similar but hopefully not missing.

That being said, I think that's a good starting point and you should also post an issue on that git so that the owner can do something about it asap.